# Why is my screen is showing simplified graphics

Tags: 14.04, graphics

[image]

What makes my desktop go like this?

Answer (score 2):

The icons seem to be part of the HighContrast icon set.
There's a few tools you can use to change your active Icon Set, i recommend you to install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).

There's 2 ways to install it:

**1)** You can [download the latest .deb file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.7/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1%7Etrusty2_all.deb) from the official website, open it up with the Software Center and hit **Install**.

**2)** Or add the PPA and install the package (It doesn't seem to have builds for any recent versions other than 14.04. So if you're **not** running Trusty then use [the .deb file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.7/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1%7Etrusty2_all.deb)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

To change your icon theme just open Ubuntu Tweak up, click the **Tweaks** tab, click **Theme**, and finally choose your **Icon Theme** on the drop-down menu.

PS: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the [Accepted Answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Worked a treat.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you! If you want to accept this as the Answer for your question, please don't forget to mark it as the [Accepted Answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).